# I have a angular grid created with *ngFor.I have placed an autocomplete inside the rows but I have troubles in modelling the same

Tags: angular, autocomplete, grid

`I know that [(ngModel)]="selected" for all in row causing issues,
I need some workaround to resolve and keep individual item in each row as[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ggAj.jpg) selected.
Presently if I select one,its reflecting in all rows because of **[(ngModel)]="selected"**.
**Please feel free to suggest any idea to populate autocomplete in such grid/table.**

```
            <table
              class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered table-light"
              style="width: 100%"
            >
                  <th>list</th>
                  <th class="th">
                    type
                    <span style="cursor: pointer"> </span>
                  </th>
                  <th (click)="sort('tmprtr')">temperatureC</th>
                  <th>temperatureF</th>
                  <th>Summary</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let c of codes; let i = index">
                  <tr>
                    
                    <td>
                      <div class="typeHead">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          list="countries"
                          [attr.list]="'countries' + i"
                          [attr.name]="'country' + i"
                          [name]="i.toString()"
                          [(ngModel)]="selected"  <!--here is the problem-->
                        />
                        <datalist [id]="'countries' + i">
                          <option
                            *ngFor="let cntrs of countrylist; let j = index"
                            [value]="c.name"
                            (click)="selectCountryName(c.name, j)"
                          ></option>
                        </datalist>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ product.temperatureC }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.temperatureF }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.summary }}</td>
                  </tr></ng-container
                >
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Use c.selected like `[(ngModel)]="c.selected"`

Comment: Thanks for your timely response.That helped.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "Selected" boolean property to the country model.

Using the global variable **this.selected** will apply to all.

([ngModel])="i.selected" will apply to each individual